# Angularjs use one controler in two views, scope is not loading

Tags: html, angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat, reload

I have an e-commerce page. I want when the user deletes a product from the shopping cart to reload the specific divs. I have the index page that contains 
a div with an ng-repeat with my products, and in the index I have an content view with the same `ng-repeat`. I want when for example I delete a
product, to update the these `ng-repeat`. I tried, the `$rootscope.$digest;` and `$scope.$apply();` but there are not working. Below, you can see my code.

My index page

```
<div ng-controller="ShoppingCartCtrl">
    <div data-toggle="dropdown"> <a href="shopping_cart.html"> </a> </div>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in resultShoppingCart">             
                    <a title="Product Title Here" ui-sref="single_product({id:item.productId})"></a>
                    <div class="product-details">
                        <div class="access"><a title="Remove This Item" ng-click="delete(userId,item.productId)">Remove</a> <a class="btn-edit" title="Edit item" ui-sref="shoppingCart"><i class="icon-pencil"></i><span class="hidden">Edit item</span></a> </div>
                        <p class="product-name"><a ui-sref="single_product({id:item.productId})" ng-bind="item.productName"></a> </p>
                        <strong ng-bind="item.quantity"></strong> x <span class="price" ng-bind="item.unitPrice"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <a ui-sref="shoppingCart"><span>View Cart</span></a>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div ui-view=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My shopping cart page

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in resultShoppingCart track by $index">
        <td class="cart_product"><a ui-sref="single_product({id:item.productId})"></a></td>
        <td class="cart_description">
            <p class="product-name" ng-bind="item.productName"></p>         
        </td>
        <td class="price" ng-bind="item.unitPrice"><span></span></td>
        <td class="qty">            
            <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-value="item.quantity" ng-model="item.quantity">
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus" ng-click="changeQuantity(item, 1)"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus" ng-click="changeQuantity(item, -1)"></i></a>                           
        </td>
        <td class="price" ng-bind="item.price"><span></span></td>
        <td class="action"><a ng-click="delete(userId,item.productId)">Delete item</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And my shopping cart controller:

```
$scope.delete = function (userId, productId) {
          var jsonDelete = '...';
          dataProvider.delete(jsonDelete).then(function (response) {   
              //$scope.$digest(); //not working
              //$scope.$apply();//not working
          });
         $state.reload();          
          //$scope.$digest;//not working
          //$scope.$apply();//not working
      };
```

With the state.reload I can reload my shopping cart page. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Few modifications will make it work.
Pass `$index` to your delete function, like,

```
ng-click="delete(userId,item.productId, $index)"
```

Then inside your `delete` handler, you can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to delete the object from your existing array. Like

```
$scope.delete = function (userId, productId, index) {
    var jsonDelete = '...';
    dataProvider.delete(jsonDelete).then(function (response) {
        $scope.resultShoppingCart.splice(index, 1);
    });
    $state.reload();
};
```

**Edit:**
Use events to update the parent value. Like,

*In shopping cart*

```
$scope.delete = function (userId, productId, index) {
    var jsonDelete = '...';
    dataProvider.delete(jsonDelete).then(function (response) {
        $scope.resultShoppingCart.splice(index, 1);
        $rootScope.$emit('updateList',productId);//Passing productid instead of index is safer as it is not necessary to stick to the order of array.
    });
    $state.reload();
};
```

*In index page*
Catch the event which is triggered after deleting.

```
$rootScope.$on('updateList', function (productId) {
    for (let i = 0; i < $scope.resultShoppingCart.length ; i++) {
        if ($scope.resultShoppingCart[i].productId == productId) {
            $scope.resultShoppingCart.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works for shopping cart page but not for the ng-repeat in my index page. Any idea?

Comment: shopping cart page is another page or inside index page?

Comment: is another page. But finally are shown both in the same page. So when I delete a product I want to update both ng-repeat

Comment: Then, when you redirect to the index, you can fetch from the server.

Comment: the page index includes the page shopping cart, so when I delete a product I want to update both ng-repeat

Comment: No it is not working, As I have two views with the same controller when I delete an item from the index it is not deleted from the shopping cart, and when I delete from shopping cart it is not deleted from the index. Only if I refresh the page I have the same items in the two views.

Comment: Just now I checked, it should work. are you adding `ng-controller` in your shoppingCart page?

Comment: Yes, I use ng-controller.I think that the scope can not be shared in the two views, something like this